# Why basic interface in type parameters causes resulting monomorphic function to use runtime.assertI2I()?

Tags: go, generics, assembly

Polymorphic function (full code see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/fq91dr46s)):

```
type Intf interface{ 
    Do() 
}
type Intf2 interface {
    Intf
    Do2()
}

func CallIntf[T Intf](intf T) {
    intf.Do()
}
```

Manual monomorph:

```
func CallIntf_mono(intf Intf) {
    intf.Do()
}
```

Instantiation:

```
    var intf2 Intf2
    intf2 = &impl{}
    CallIntf[Intf](intf2)
```

Instantiation asm (contains a call to `runtime.assertI2I()`):

```
    LEAQ    type."".impl(SB), AX
    CALL    runtime.newobject(SB)
    MOVQ    AX, ""..autotmp_13+24(SP)
    LEAQ    go.itab.*"".impl,"".Intf2(SB), BX
    LEAQ    type."".Intf(SB), AX
    CALL    runtime.convI2I(SB)
    MOVQ    AX, BX
    MOVQ    ""..autotmp_13+24(SP), CX
    LEAQ    ""..dict.CallIntf["".Intf](SB), AX
    CALL    "".CallIntf[go.shape.interface { Do() }_0](SB)
```

Generated monomorphic function asm (contains a call to `runtime.assertI2I()`):

```
    TEXT    "".CallIntf[go.shape.interface { Do() }_0](SB), DUPOK|ABIInternal, $32-24
    MOVQ    CX, "".intf+56(SP)
    LEAQ    type."".Intf(SB), AX
    CALL    runtime.assertI2I(SB)
    MOVQ    24(AX), CX
    MOVQ    "".intf+56(SP), AX
    CALL    CX
    MOVQ    24(SP), BP
    ADDQ    $32, SP
    RET
```

Manual monomorph asm (does not call `runtime.assertI2I()`):

```
    TEXT    "".CallIntf_mono(SB), ABIInternal, $16-16
    MOVQ    AX, "".intf+24(FP)
    MOVQ    BX, "".intf+32(FP)
    MOVQ    24(AX), CX
    MOVQ    BX, AX
    CALL    CX
    MOVQ    8(SP), BP
    ADDQ    $16, SP
    RET
```

Question: Why does the assembly of the generated monomorphic function use `runtime.assertI2I()`, while the one of the manual monomorphic function does not? In which case caller would use a type which needs to be asserted?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Both CallIntf_mono() and  CallIntf[T Intf]() panic if nil is passed as an argument. Monomorph throws more crude SIGSEGV though.

Comment: Yes but I do not understand how it is related to the question. Both CallIntf_mono() and CallIntf[T Intf]() panic, so extra call to runtime.assertI2I() does not make significant difference in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get confirmation elsewhere, so I'm just going to post my intuition here.

What you see is likely due to the current implementation of Go generics, which is based on [GC Stenciling](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/generics-implementation-dictionaries-go1.18.md). GC stands for Garbage Collector.

The executive summary is:

> [...], for simplicity (and performance) of implementation, we do not have a single compilation of a generic function/method for all possible type arguments. Instead, we share an instantiation of a generic function/method among sets of type arguments that have the same gcshape.

A gcshape is a group of types that "look the same" to the garbage collector. More formally, types that have the same underlying type, or pointers.

The identifier `go.shape.interface { Do() }_0` seen in your ASM is the gcshape of the `Intf` interface, used as a type parameter constraint, where `go.shape` is a builtin package and `interface { Do() }` is the underlying type of `Intf`.

Based on my understanding, the above implies that **generic functions aren't truly monomorphized** upon instantiation. So the pseudo-register `SB` ends up having the gcshape of the interface, not the interface itself. For this reason, `runtime.assertI2I(SB)` is used to ensure that the two interfaces are compatible.

Anyway this is all implementation details. The ASM may change with future Go releases, and even point releases. At the time of writing, the assertion is still present in Go 1.18.3 compiled code.

Comment: Thanks, but then the next question arises - why use runtime.assertI2I(SB)  from CallIntf[T Intf] provided caller already invoked runtime.convI2I(SB)?

Comment: @maxim_ge that's probably because in your godbolt snippet you've got `CallIntf[Intf](intf2)`, i.e. the function is being instantiated with `Intf` explicitly but the argument is of type `Intf2`. If you change the argument to be just `Intf`, the `runtime.convI2I` doesn't appear in the ASM anymore. The conversion is the [implied conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) that happens when assigning different but compatible types, e.g. through func args

Comment: I mean, `convI2I` involves `Intf` and `Intf2`, whereas `assertI2I` involves the argument and the gcshape

Comment: Yes, sure - that's a deliberate case which forces caller to do interface conversion. So far I think that there is no extra need to call  runtime.assertI2I(SB) since caller always does convI2I(), if needed.